# Local gem installed by Bundler is removed automatically

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I want to install a local gem using Bundler. I edited `Gemfile` as below:

```
~
gem "example_gem","=0.0.1",:path => "~/ruby/mygem/example/pkg"
~
```

and executed:

```
bundle install
```

The result is:

```
Resolving dependencies...
~
Using example_gem 0.0.1 from source at ~/ruby/mygem/example_gem/pkg
~
Using bundler 1.6.3
Your bundle is complete!
```

I normally use `"example_gem"` in my project, but `"example_gem"` was deleted from directory `"~/ruby/mygem/example_gem/pkg"`. I don't want it to be deleted from that directory. Please tell me how to avoid deleting local gems when using Bundler.

Comment: Strange your gem gets deleted. Since ~-expansion is usually handled by the shell (or here your interpreter) I am not too sure what it will do. Could you try to specify the full path?

Comment: thanks to translate and response to this question. I tried to change full path,but occured same result.

Comment: You could try to set the path using a `bundle config` setting as [described here](https://coderwall.com/p/tqdrhq) instead of setting your `:path` in the `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks.I solved this problem.